# Windows Process-Wide Security for Java via registry keys

Tags: windows, windows-registry, java, acl, com

My goal is to configure COM/DCOM security for my Java OPC DA **client** (*not server*).

The main problem is that every time the client tries to get updates from a OPC DA server in **asynchronous** mode, it fails with the following error in Windows Event Viewer:

```
The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user 
DESKTOP-AAAAA\Admin SID (S-1-5-21-239355189-745547292-2783995333-1001) 
from address 192.168.0.5 to activate DCOM server.
```

*Note, both client and server run on my laptop (192.168.0.5 is just my IP address of my Wi-Fi adapter)*

If the client was written in C++, I could call the Windows API called [CoInitializeSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializesecurity). For Java I can't do this, so I would like to configure it via Windows Registry in key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{AppID_GUID}`, as it is described in [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/setting-processwide-security-through-the-registry).

According to the aforementioned documentation, I need to set up at least 3 registry values `AuthenticationLevel`, `LaunchPermission` and `AccessPermission`. The latter two are binary data that represents the Access Control List (ACL).

Now I have several questions:

1. Where I can get `AppID_GUID` for java.exe
2. [Solved](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/a28706ff-216c-437d-8210-311dd7dd93c5/how-to-grant-component-servicesdcom-permissions-for-an-application-via-gpo-ssis?forum=winserverGP) (thanks to [@Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier)) How to manually create values for `LaunchPermission` and `AccessPermission`?

For more information on the problem, here is [my SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76061241/17782348).

Comment: FWIW If the CoInitializeSecurity call needs EXE you can package your application as EXE with jpackage (JDK14+), and you can make any Windows API calls from Java using Foreign Memory + LInker API incubating in JDK16, now preview JDK20. Best not to put all that into one question though.

Comment: @DuncG Unfortunately, our app is still on Java 8

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion here regarding COM and APPID.

`Java.exe` is just a simple executable. Although a COM server can be
*implemented* in the Java language and executed at run-time by `java.exe`,
the executable itself has no built-in capabilities as a COM server,
so has no APPID.

In addition, an OPC DA client is also not a COM server and so doesn't
also have an APPID.

Reading material :
[How does OPC work in conjunction with COM to identify unique OPC Servers?](https://honeywellprocess.my.site.com/opcsupport/s/article/How-does-OPC-work-in-conjunction-with-COM-to-identify-unique-OPC-ServersRef-KB-993)

Comment: From Microsoft article (link is in my post): `For a COM client that is not a server, this mapping is not created because the client is never registered. Therefore, to set security using the AppID key, the client must create the necessary registry entries, either programmatically by using the registry functions or by using regedit.`

Comment: Yes, but what would you achieve with that? From [Security in COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/security-in-com?source=recommendations) : "There are two main types of security in COM: activation security and call security. Activation security determines whether a client can launch a server at all. After a server has been launched, you can use call security to control access to a server's objects." Will your client be launching a COM server?

Comment: Yes, my Java OPC DA client needs both permissions to asynchronously get updates from a server. Now I get error `The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user 
DESKTOP-AAAAA\Admin SID (S-1-5-21-239355189-745547292-2783995333-1001) 
from address 192.168.0.5 to activate DCOM server. ` Here is [original SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76061241/how-to-force-j-interop-using-ncalrpc-for-localhost?noredirect=1#comment134318026_76061241). Note, both client and server run on my laptop

Comment: That's entirely different - I'll need to rethink my answer. In the meantime, this information will be useful for others to answer. It might be a good idea to incorporate it in your post.

Comment: For calling CoInitializeSecurity from Java see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953419/jna-e-outofmemory). There is also ]this link](https://www.javatips.net/api/oshi-master/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/jna/platform/windows/Ole32.java).